# How to write a unit test a custom Filter in Django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django, so maybe this is very simple, but I have been trying to make sense of the documentation all day and I need some help, some way to going in the right direction.
Basically, I have a Custom Filter class, like this

```
class CustomFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    username = BooleanFilter(method='filter_current_user')
    ...
```

And inside, several methods, being the following the simpler of them

```
def filter_current_user(self, queryset, name, value):
        if value is True:
            return queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return queryset
```

How can I write a test that validates the differences of the queryset returned when value is True and when value is False?
My biggest problem is how make that the `self` value contains the `request.user`.

Comment: Also, I found this link in the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section of SO, [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), which clearly indicate I didn't rude to you by asking about the effort

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found for testing a filter class is to validate the raw query that is produced with it:

```
class ConversationFilter(ConversationFilterSet):
    created = filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=CREATED_CHOICES, method="filter_created")

    def filter_created(self, queryset: QuerySet, name: str, value: str) -> QuerySet:
        if value:
            if value == "more_than_7_days":
                time_stop = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=7)
                return queryset.filter(created_time__lte=time_stop)
            elif value == "last_12_hours":
                value_serialized = timedelta(hours=12)
            elif value == "last_24_hours":
                value_serialized = timedelta(hours=24)
            elif value == "last_3_days":
                value_serialized = timedelta(days=3)
            elif value == "last_7_days":
                value_serialized = timedelta(days=7)
            else:
                raise ValueError(value)
            time_start = timezone.now() - value_serialized
            queryset = queryset.filter(created_time__gte=time_start)

        return queryset


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("db")
class TestConversationFilter:
    def test_filter_created_more_than(self):
        queryset = Conversation.objects.all()
        view = ConversationsInboxViewSet.as_view({"get": "list"})
        conversation_filter = ConversationFilter(view=view)
        filtered_queryset = conversation_filter.filter_created(
            queryset, "created", "more_than_7_days"
        )

        # We're checking only the datetime up to the level of seconds - below that we'd need to add
        # The time required to evaluate the expression etc.
        created_time_parameter: str = (timezone.now() - timedelta(days=7)).strftime(
            "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        )

        assert (
            f'WHERE "conversations_conversation"."created_time" <= {created_time_parameter}'
            in str(filtered_queryset.query)
        )
```